# Проблемы со строками в функции. (Подробнее в вопросе)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Наша функция будет возвращать строку с полным именем `'first_name middle_name last_name'`, если же `middle_name` отсутствует, то возвращаемая строка должна быть `'first_name last_name'`.

И вот код:

```py
def get_fullname (first_name, last_name,  middle_name ):
    return (f'{first_name}  {last_name} {middle_name}')
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: А сама ошибка та какая?

Comment: Функция get_fullname вернула неправильный результат для полного имени: Petro Ivanovich Zaliznyak.Во,я даже хз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите сделать так, чтобы аргумент в функции можно было не передавать, то ему надо дать аргумент по умолчанию. Тогда ваш код будет выглядеть вот так:

```
def get_fullname(first_name, last_name, middle_name=' '):
    return (f"{first_name}{middle_name if ' ' == middle_name else f' {middle_name} '}{last_name}")

def get_fullname_second(first_name, last_name, middle_name=''):
    return ' '.join(filter(lambda ele: ele != '', (first_name, middle_name, last_name)))

print(get_fullname('Test', 'Test1', 'Test2'))
print(get_fullname('Test', 'Test1'))
```

Вывод

```
Test Test2 Test1
Test Test1
```

Comment: У вас неправильный порядок. И один лишний пробел в конце

Comment: Я не совсем понял задание изначально. Ответ исправил, но он немного костыльный.

Comment: Похоже, что теперь это верный ответ :) Но выглядит некрасиво. Я бы попробовал метод `join`. Ему можно передать список, перед этим отфильтровав

Comment: Я попробовал join, но не совсем понял, как тогда исключать элемент middle_Name. А если его не убирать, будет появляться лишний пробел при ' '.join. И тогда всё сведётся к такому же некрасивому решению.

Comment: ЕЕЕ,заработалоспасибо

Comment: Отфильтруйте значения списка. Можете использовать стандартную функцию `filter`

Comment: Добавил ещё один вариант =)

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_fullname (first_name, last_name,  middle_name='' ):
    return (f'{first_name} {last_name} {middle_name}').strip()
```

Воспользуйтесь значением по умолчанию для переменной middle_name и strip для удаления лишнего пробела.

Comment: Я пробовал значение по умолчанию,щас добавил strip и все равно та же ошибка

Comment: У вас неправильный порядок

Comment: Какая ошибка выводится?

Comment: Функция get_fullname вернула неправильный результат для полного имени: Petro Ivanovich Zaliznyak

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, вам нужно поменять переменные last_name и middle_name местами.

Comment: Отправьте то, что вы вводите или ошибку, которую вы получаете.

Comment: Функция get_fullname вернула неправильный результат для полного имени: Petro Zaliznyak Ivanovich - ошибка

Comment: Давайте напишем функцию, которая возвращает полное имя пользователя. В базе данных в основном хранят имя пользователя first_name, его фамилию last_name и отчество, или, как принято в западных странах, второе имя — middle_name. Причем middle_name — это необязательная переменная, она может быть, а может и не передаваться при вызове функции. Наша функция будет возвращать строку с полным именем 'first_name middle_name last_name', если же middle_name отсутствует, то возвращаемая строка должна быть 'first_name last_name' - вот сама задача

Comment: Передавайте переменные в явном виде: get_fullname(first_name='Petro', last_name='Zaliznyak', middle_name='Ivanovich')

Answer (score 0):

Переменную `middle_name` можно сделать [аргументом по умолчанию](https://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/argumenty-po-umolchaniyu-v-funkciyah-python.html), подставив в качестве запасного варианта пустую строку `''`. Таким образом, даже не вводя `middle_name`, функция будет получать пустую строку в данную переменную.

Тогда ещё нужно изменить порядок вывода переменных в строке:

```py
def get_fullname (first_name, last_name,  middle_name=''):
    return (f'{first_name} {middle_name} {last_name}')
```

Comment: Между `first_name` и `last_name` будет 2 пробела

Comment: попробовал поменять местами ,все равно не получается

Answer (score 0):

```py
def get_fullname(first_name, /, last_name=None, middle_name=None):
    return ' '.join(filter(None, [first_name, middle_name, last_name]))

print(get_fullname('Vjacheslav', 'Fetisov', 'Aleksandrovich'))
print(get_fullname('Vjacheslav', 'Fetisov'))

# Vjacheslav Aleksandrovich Fetisov
# Vjacheslav Fetisov
```